# WordPress admin returns "Can’t select database"

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

UPDATE:
Well Thanks for your support guys. The problem was at the server side. It has been resolved now and my site is up & running.

Kindly visit www.bestlappyforme.tk
and send me feedback & suggestions at bestlappyforme@gmail.com
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Please guide dear friend, how to do that as i m completely new

Comment: Brother i m a new bie - i can't understand which code you want. I m sorry about that. Are you asking for wp-config.php?

Comment: If you haven't made a change to the config, then it is probably on the other side. Have you checked the database?

Comment: Yes i can access phpmyadmin - It looks fine. I also restored a latest version of database backup. But nothing happened. However, i see "No Privileges" under "check privileges" option

Comment: @user6563252 first thing you need to check whether database exists in your server. Second thing is your local database name is your server database name is u217713781_wp2 ? If it so, please check that your server should have database prefix.

Comment: @ user2584538, yes the database exists. Also the name is same in Phpmyadmin

Comment: @user6563252 without any prefix for database ? As well have you correctly assigned user to the database ?

Comment: yes the prefix itself is u217713781

Comment: @user6563252 It seems your database server is down. Please contact the server admin.

Comment: I do not know what to do. Server's admin has no email

Comment: who is the hosting provider ? Please contact the Hosting Provider.

Comment: www.hostinger.in

Comment: have you checked the error_log ?

Comment: Yes i checked it now. it has some weird errors in    wp.db. Wait for a moment, i will share with you the Complete error log

Comment: This is mu error log ( i have no idea what does it mean) . [03-Jan-2018 10:26:30 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'u217713781_user2@localhost'@'10.2.1.5' (using password: YES) in /home/u217713781/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1538
[03-Jan-2018 10:26:51 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli_real_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'u217713781_user2@localhost'@'10.2.1.5' (using password: YES) in /home/u217713781/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1538

Answer (score 0):

**If that error show**

Are you sure it exists? Does the user.. have permission to use the ... database?

**Solution,**

If you did want to lock things down.... a normal wordpress site will usually only require the database user to have SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE.

If you want to use the automatic update feature it will also require CREATE and ALTER.

INSERT, UPDATE, and SELECT are used all the time.[image]

**If Database Connection in WordPress than,**

You can do this by adding the following line in your wp-config.php file. Add it just before ‘That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging’ line wp-config.php.

```
define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

Remember, the user does not need to be logged in to access this functionality when this define is set. This is because its main intent is to repair a corrupted database, Users can often not login when the database is corrupt. So once you are done repairing and optimizing your database, make sure to remove this from your wp-config.php.

**Checking the WP-Config file**

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database-name');
define('DB_USER', 'database-username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'database-password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Some folks suggested that they fixed their problem by replacing localhost with the IP. It is common to see this sort of issue when running WordPress on a local server environment. For example on MAMP, the DB_Host value when changed to the IP may seem to work.

```
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:8889');
```

Comment: I have all the features marked as "tick" in cpanel of My SQL Database

Comment: do you try this  define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true); ?

Comment: Yes bro I did, But it shows same error - CAN'T SELECT DATABASE.

Comment: check that link may be useful for you https://makeawebsitehub.com/fix-database-error-wordpress/

Comment: i check your that url  : https://www.bestlappyforme.tk/wp-admin/.   your problem is on database not select. please reconfirm database name.

Comment: MySQL Data Base Name: u217713781_wp2

Comment: okay and is that username and password is correct ? Reconfirm its

Comment: My SQL USER NAME :  u217713781_user2

Comment: MY SQL HOST NAME: mysql.hostinger.in

Comment: Please don't share your username and password but check othervice change both username and password than change config file once again.

Comment: It is absolutely correct. Shall i change the password?

Comment: Change database user username and password and change also config file. than you can test.

Comment: Ok i m on it. I will inform you

Comment: I tried it , new error pops up - Error establishing Database Connection This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at mysql.hostinger.in. This could mean your host’s database server is down.

Are you sure you have the correct username and password?
Are you sure that you have typed the correct hostname?
Are you sure that the database server is running?
If you’re unsure what these terms mean you should probably contact your host. If you still need help you can always visit the WordPress Suppor.

Comment: I know i cheeked your link. it's error tell that your database or username or password or hostname is incorrect.

Comment: Is there any hope??

Answer (score 0):

your hosting account is it shared hosting? As some actually require your hosting username_mysqluser as the db username and username_mysqldbname
Password can be anything

Please always make sure your host is localhost to avoid any configuration issues unless you are connecting to a remote server

Also endeavour to check the spelling and your dbname has been created and not empty, please check in a calm manner as even experts also tend to check in a tense manner and still won't find anything

Comment: Yes it is a shared hosting at www.hostinger.in. I have never tried or attempted to connect to remote server ( i do not even know what the hell it is...). Also, i have checked my wp-config.php file more than 10 times, everything is correct.

Comment: What of the hosting username_mysqluser ?

Comment: @user6563252 have you checked it out?

Comment: My Hosting username is u217713781_user2. I have included a link of phpmyadmin image above

Comment: So it will probably be u217713781_user2_mysqluser.      That is your hostingusername_mysqluser

Comment: Not the _mysqluser portion. It is just u217713781_user2

Comment: You need to add the _mysqluser portion. That is if you are not adding the mysqluser portion it means your mysql user is u217713781_user2 and you have assigned the user specifically to that database you are trying to connect to not just the host, as the host will connect with the right username and password but the db won't if you don't assign the user to it.

Comment: For Which the creation of mysql user or the assigning a user to a db?

Comment: Assigning user to database

Comment: In the area where you create a mysql user for the database in a normal cpanel, usually at the bottom of that page you will see two select option boxes, one for the db one for the user

Comment: There is no such option at www.hostinger.in cpanel

Comment: I can assist if you don't mind, if you'd would give me access to your cpanel, but it has to be in a message or chat.

Comment: I m ready to do anything which restores my site. I fully believe on you. How shall I share it?

Comment: Send details tp to you, kindly confirm

Comment: I have replied your mail

Answer (score 0):

Give all privileges to the database user by adding the database to that user after that it should work. If not then change password of database user and edit the `wp-config.php` file accordingly.

Comment: Did that too brother several times. No change. The error still continues

Comment: If you don't mind, can you share your hosting credentials. Definitely I will resolve it.

Comment: I have raised a ticket to my hosting support & they are trying to resolve it. If it fails, i will definitely share the details with you. Kindly share your whatsapp number at bestlappyforme@gmail.com

Comment: Dear Friend, the error is resolved. Thank you for your support. Kindly visit my site at www.bestlappyforme.tk & provide suggestions.